# How to find position of similar numbers in a list

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

Given a list of elements, with certain similar elements in it, how do I write a code in Python to find the **position** of all the **similar** elements in it? This must be done using a for loop and if conditions within the for loop.

```
list1 = [5, 90, 10, 5, 100, 5]
```

So in this case, since 5 is the element that has repeats or ties, the output will be 0,3,5.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Any possible approaches in mind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python)

Comment: *"This must be done using a for loop and if conditions within the for loop."* This is what we would like to tell you as well. Try and later come back with a specific question if you're stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `set` to find the unique set of elements in the `list` and then check for indexes of the repeated elements.

Try the code below:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list1 = [5, 90, 10, 5, 100, 5]

set1 = set(list1)
res_dict = defaultdict(list)

for x in set1:
    for i, y in enumerate(list1):
        if x == y:
            res_dict[x].append(i)

print res_dict
```

**Output:**

```
{90: [1], 100: [4], 10: [2], 5: [0, 3, 5]}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `enumerate` inside **list comprehension** for **5**,

```
>>> list1 = [5, 90, 10, 5, 100, 5]
>>> all_index = [i for i, j in enumerate(list1) if j == 5]
>>> all_index
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 3, 5]
```

With loop for all element,

```
list1 = [5, 90, 10, 5, 100, 5]
result = {}
for e in list1:
    result[e] = [i for i, j in enumerate(list1) if j == e]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
 {90: [1], 10: [2], 100: [4], 5: [0, 3, 5]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using np.where will get you what you want:

```
import numpy as np

list1 = [5, 90, 10, 5, 100, 5]

data = np.array(list1)
unique = sorted(list(set(data)))

match = {}
for i in range(len(unique)):
    match[unique[i]] = np.where(data == unique[i])[0]

print(match)
>>> {5: array([0, 3, 5]), 10: array([2]), 90: array([1]), 100: array([4])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only a for loop and if conditions:

```
input_list = [5, 90, 100, 5, 100, 5]

elements = {}
result = []

for i, e in enumerate(input_list):
    if e in elements:
        if not elements[e][1]:
            result.append(elements[e][0])
            elements[e][1] = True
        result.append(i)
    else:
        elements[e] = [i, False]

print(sorted(result))
```